# Incorrect syntax near outer join in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying this query to fetch data from two table. I am getting the error on join.

```
select  
  bundlechecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID,
  documentchecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID,
  documentchecklist.Doc_Type_Name 
from 
  bundle_checklist_txn bundlechecklist
outer join 
  Document_Checklist_TXN documentchecklist on
  documentchecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID = bundlechecklist.Bundle_TXN_ID
where 
  bundlechecklist.originating_tran_id = "AMD1256" and bundle_name = "Line"
```

Please help me in fixing the error

Comment: yes, you should use a join that actually exists. Either `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Oh ya! that worked ! Thank you